# Difficulty changing style of google map on button click

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I have a map using the google map api and I'm trying to change the water color on a button click.
I've been struggling with this one for a while now.

I initialised the map variable outside of the initMap function but that didn't seem to change anything.

```
    var map;
    function initMap() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

            center: {              
                lat: 40.674,
                lng: -73.945               
            },
            zoom: 12,
            styles: [
                {
                    featureType: 'water',
                    elementType: 'geology',
                    stylers: [{color: '#17263c'}]
            }
            ]               
        });         
    }

    function showTest() {

        var myStyle =[{
            featureType: 'water',
            elementType: 'geometry',
            stylers: [
                { color: '#fc0101' }
            ]
        }];

    map.setOptions({styles: myStyle});
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you initialised a map variable outside your initMap function, the fact you then declare a map variable inside that function prefixed with `var`, makes it local to just that function.

Change that to:

```
 function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
```

Comment: Oh my god, Ive been trying to figure this out for so long. One of those days I guess.

Comment: @JacobRiches Do mark this as the right answer if it helped you solve your issue.